# PostgreSQL: Check the structure of foreign tables

Tags: postgresql-11, postgresql-fdw

How can I check if the structure of a foreign table was changed in the source database in order to know when to re import it. Foreign table was imported by foreign-data wrapper postgres_fdw (PostgreSQL 11.2).

Comment: What is the PostgreSQL version(x,y,z)?

Comment: PostgreSQL 11.2

Answer (score 1):

> How can I check if the structure of a foreign table was changed in the
>   source database in order to know when to re import it. Foreign table
>   was imported by foreign-data wrapper postgres_fdw.

As [here](https://thoughtbot.com/blog/postgres-foreign-data-wrapper) and [here](https://www.2ndquadrant.com/en/blog/postgresql-9-5-import-foreign-schema/) if you’ve imported your schema, then you can query the foreign tables as if they were normal, local tables.

For further your ref [postgres_fdw](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/postgres-fdw.html) and [IMPORT FOREIGN SCHEMA](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/sql-importforeignschema.html)

Comment: yes, I can query the content of foreign table as if it was normal, but can I query its structure? e.g. if in the original database somebody added/dropped/renamed a column to the table, can I get this (structural) information in the context of the database where this table is imported as a foreign table?